# Calling a xib when custom view is called from xib causes a crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, runtime-error

In one .xib file I add one view and modify its class to be my `CustomViewClass`. Inside that class I have the rewriting method which has been called when the .xib is created:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
if(self == [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){
    //Load  the xib
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SliderVW" owner:nil options:Nil];
    self = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}
return self;
}
```

This method calls one xib to assign to self view to the `CustomViewClass` but something is wrong; I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SliderVW" owner:nil options:Nil];
```

but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below and see if it works:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SliderVW" owner:self options:nil];
```

Have changed the argument "nil" to "self" for owner.

Comment: Looking at your scenario you don't need this call in you class:
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SliderVW" owner:self options:nil];

This is because you can use this custom view directly by creating an outlet for that view in the .xib in which you have used that view.